# How to trigger a Jenkins test AFTER deploying on heroku?

Tags: jenkins, heroku

**Here is my "code pushing workflow":**

Code gets pushed to GitHub, where a few tests are automatically ran by another CI/CD platform (not Jenkins).

Once those tests pass, the code is automatically pushed to our staging app on heroku.

To push in production, we promote the staging app manually on heroku.

**What I want to add:**

We have a test on a separate Jenkins server, its purpose is to test the subscription process of our app **in production**. So it would make sense to trigger that test right after a new build in production.

**The solution I'm considering now:**

Since Heroku does not propose to add post-promotion steps and Jenkins cannot guess when a promotion has happened (correct me if I'm wrong!), the solution I'm considering now is to write a small bash script that would look like this:

`heroku pipelines:promote -a stagingApp         // promote the app
JENKINS_URL/job/ourtest/build?token=TOKEN_NAME // run the Jenkins tests`

Seems reasonable; it implies changing the workflow from clicking a button on Heroku to running a bash script. But if any better/simpler/bash-scripting-less solution is out there I'd love to hear about it.

Cheers!